# ScintillaNet and RoutedCommands

Tags: c#, wpf, command, scintilla

I am using a ScintillaNet edit control in my C# WPF application. In my main window I have a few RoutedCommands setup. The ScintillaNet control is hosted inside a WindowsFormsHost. The RoutedCommands are not working when the ScintillaNet control has focus.

I tried capturing the key strokes and manually executing the RoutedCommands but CanExecute always fails:

```
WindowsFormsHost wfh = new WindowsFormsHost();
Scintilla editor = new Scintilla();
wfh.Child = editor;
wfh.Child.PreviewKeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(Child_PreviewKeyDown);

....

void Child_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.F5)
        // Window1 is the main window class
        // handle is a reference to the main window
        if (Window1.CmdRun.CanExecute(wfh, handle)) {
            Window1.CmdRun.Execute(wfh, handle);
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("CANT EXECUTE");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly?

Thanks